# Coercing function using type families leads to constraint error

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have some type class with a type family:

```
class MyClass t where
    data Fam t :: *
    myfun :: t -> Fam t
instance MyClass Int where
    newtype Fam Int = Triv Int
    myfun = Triv
```

(Simplified a lot compared to my actual use-case to avoid clutter.)

Now suppose I want to provide a default implementation for any type that can be embedded into something that is already an instance of the type class. I would think I could write something like this:

```
class (MyClass (Embed t)) => Embeddable t where
    type Embed t :: *
    embed :: t -> Embed t
newtype MyNewtype t = MyConstructor t
instance (Embeddable t) => MyClass (MyNewtype t) where
    newtype Fam (MyNewtype t) = MyFam (Fam (Embed t))
    myfun (MyConstructor x) = MyFam (myfun . embed $ x)
myfunDef :: forall t. (Coercible (Fam (MyNewtype t)) (Fam t)) => t -> Fam t
myfunDef = coerce (myfun :: MyNewtype t -> Fam (MyNewtype t))
```

The problem is that this doesn't compile:

```
 • Could not deduce: Embed t ~ t arising from a use of ‘coerce’
      from the context: Coercible (Fam (MyNewtype t)) (Fam t)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   myfunDef :: forall t.
                               Coercible (Fam (MyNewtype t)) (Fam t) =>
                               t -> Fam t
        at src/Lib.hs:22:1-75
      ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          myfunDef :: forall t.
                      Coercible (Fam (MyNewtype t)) (Fam t) =>
                      t -> Fam t
        at src/Lib.hs:22:1-75
    • In the expression:
        coerce (myfun :: MyNewtype t -> Fam (MyNewtype t))
      In an equation for ‘myfunDef’:
          myfunDef = coerce (myfun :: MyNewtype t -> Fam (MyNewtype t))
    • Relevant bindings include
        myfunDef :: t -> Fam t (bound at src/Lib.hs:23:1)
   |
23 | myfunDef = coerce (myfun :: MyNewtype t -> Fam (MyNewtype t))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can't figure out why this error is there or how to solve it.

If it had compiled, I had intended to use it like so:

```
instance Embeddable Bool where
    type Embed Bool = Int
    embed False = 0
    embed True = 1
instance MyClass Bool where
    newtype Fam Bool = BoolFam (Fam (Embed Bool))
    myfun = myfunDef
```

Obviously in this case `MyClass Bool` would have been relatively simple to implement directly, but imagine a case where it had been more complicated.

Comment: That sounds like a GHC bug.

Comment: `Could not deduce: Embed t ~ t`: Do you want that to hold? You don't have any instances for `Embeddable`, nor any constraints to require it to hold. Also in your proposed instance for `Embeddable Bool`, it doesn't hold. `(Coercible (Fam (MyNewtype t)) (Fam t))` constraint on `myfunDef` I think will need an infinite type  `MyNewtype t ~ t`. Data families are injective.

Comment: I don't want `Embed t ~ t` to hold, but I don't understand why it requires it to hold. In my proposed instance for `MyClass Bool`, `Fam Bool` should be represented as `Fam (Embed Bool)`, i.e. `Fam Int`; while `Fam (MyNewtype Bool)` should also be represented as `Fam (Embed Bool)`; so I'd think they would be coercible to each other.